# How do I install libqt4.7.4?

Tags: package-management, qt

I need to use libqt4.7.4 (or .3) on the latest build of Ubuntu. Is there any easy way to revert to that version. Will it break anything?

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools=4.7.4 errors with 'Version not found'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This, is not possible with repositories of ubuntu, you can uninstall qt via apt-get and install Qt from site:
       http://qt-project.org/downloads or
       ftp://ftp.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/ 
or searh a repository with Qt